# How to set path and environment variables in Python (Windows OS)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line, environment-variables, windows-11

I use [this](https://%3Chttps://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HyxR0QTTJJs%3E) tutorial to set paths for Anaconda and Python.  .
For Anaconda i was able to set up the path, but not for Python. When I look where the Python is located in Anaconda Prompt by typing "where python" i get two results:

> C:\Users\John\anaconda3\python.exe

&

> C:\Users\John\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe

No matter which one of the directories i use in environment variables, it doesn't work. I mean, when i check the python version in command line, it doesn't show me the version.
I did step by step according to what was in the tutorial.
In general, I wrote a code which creates text file and write something, and I want to run this file from command line. You can see what i mean in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqnJvXOIr6g) tutorial at 7:30.
Do you have any suggestions how can I set a path for python and maybe give advice to achieve the desired result?

Comment: Go through the setup guide provided on the Real Python website. https://realpython.com/python-coding-setup-windows/